# Continuity of a function containing infinite sum of floor function

Tags: limits, continuity, limits-without-lhopital, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to find the points of discontinuity of the following function $$f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{\lfloor2rx\rfloor}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Using Stolz theorem:
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{\lfloor 2rx\rfloor}{n^2} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\lfloor2nx\rfloor}{n^2-(n-1)^2} =  \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\lfloor2nx\rfloor}{2n-1} = x $$
Note that for the last limit you use squeeze theorem.

So the function is continuous

Answer (score 1):

Let $x>0$. Notice that $$\frac{2rx - 1} {n} \leq \frac{\lfloor 2rx \rfloor} {n} \leq \frac{2rx}{n} $$
Hence $$-\frac 1 n+\frac 1 n\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2rx } {n} \leq \frac 1 n \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\lfloor 2rx \rfloor} {n}\leq \frac 1 n\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2rx}{n}$$
You can see the summation on the LHS (and RHS) as a Riemann sum: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 n\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2rx } {n}=x\int^1_0 2t\, dt = x$$
The squeeze theorem finishes the proof that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\lfloor 2rx \rfloor} {n}=x $$ A similar  argument could be applied for $x<0$ yielding the same result. For $x=0$ the limit is zero. So the function in question is continuous.