# I found a really interesting sum involving the floor function. Can someone help explain why it works the way it does?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions

NOTE: This is all from Desmos and manually plugging in numbers and solving to find lines. There has been no proof done of what I'm talking about, and I don't really know the math necessary to do such a proof.

Here's the sum: $\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{p^{2}}=\frac{x}{2}$. I'd really like to understand why this works. For powers of $p$ greater than $2$, this goes to $0$ and powers of $p$ less than $2$ it goes to $\infty$, but it's not clear at all to me that that would be how it converges. Can someone help go through a proof of this or at least explain a bit of why it would go to $\frac{x}{2}$ in one place and collapse/diverge everywhere else?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2844060/42969

Comment: @MartinR That's really interesting! In that one, the function's a bit different, but the proof should be pretty similar. What I'd like to ask about is powers of p other than 2, though.

Comment: It is the *same* function, only with $2x$ instead of $x$.

Comment: @MartinR It is the same function, I said it a bit confusingly. When I said "powers of $p$", I specifically meant replacing the $p^{2}$ inside the sum with another power, like $p^{3}$ or $p^{1.5}$, etc.

Comment: OK, so you are asking about $\displaystyle\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{p}\dfrac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{p^{e}}$ for exponents $e$ less or greater than $2$. I suggest to clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exponent $2$ is “special” because $\lfloor nx \rfloor \sim nx$ for $x \ne 0$ and large $n$, and
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^p n = \frac 12 p(p+1)
$$
is a *quadratic* polynomial in $p$.

For positive integers $p$, real $a > 0$ and real $x \ne 0$ is
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{ \lfloor nx \rfloor}{p^{a}} \le \sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{ nx }{p^{a}}
= \frac{p(p+1)}{2p^a} x
= \frac{1}{p^{a-2}} \cdot \frac{p+1}{p}\cdot \frac x2
$$
and
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{p^{a}} \ge \sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{ nx -1}{p^{a}}
= \frac{p(p+1)}{2p^a} x - \frac{1}{p^{a-1}}
= \frac{1}{p^{a-2}} \cdot \frac{p+1}{p} \cdot \frac x2 \left(1 - \frac{2}{(p+1)x} \right) \, .
$$
For $p \to \infty$ both the lower bound and the upper bound

- converge to zero if $a > 2$,
- converge to $x/2$ if $a=2$, and
- diverge to $\pm \infty$ (depending on the sign of $x$) if $a < 2$.

Comment: Please choose another letter for the constant $e$: when I read $e=2$ I got shivers XD

Comment: @Joako: I do not think that there is a real ambiguity (and $e$ is used for an exponent also in other contexts, like the RSA algorithm). But I have renamed it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, given that it converges with exponent $2$. Suppose the exponent is $2+\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ (noting that $p^{2+\varepsilon}=p^2\cdot p^\varepsilon$):

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{p^{2+\varepsilon}}=\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac1{p^\varepsilon}\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{p^2}\right)$$
$$=\left(\lim_{p\to\infty}\frac1{p^\varepsilon}\right)\left(\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{p^2}\right)$$
$$=0\cdot\frac x2$$
$$=0$$

Similarly, if the exponent is $2-\varepsilon$ then you get $(\lim_{p\to\infty} p^\varepsilon)\cdot\tfrac x2=\infty\cdot\tfrac x2$.